# How can I offer options to save data to a user from an rpm?

Tags: linux, unix, rpm

I deliver an application via an RPM.
What I need to do is if the user uninstalls the application (`rpm -e`) to get a chance to do a back up of some the files that are part of the application installed.
Additionally on (post) installation I want the user to get a chance to replace some of the installation's files with the ones that he saved during a previous uninstall.

To do this I thought to make an interactive RPM.
But it did not work. Googling I found that some of the commands e.g. `read` are ignored in an RPM spec somehow and additionally the idea to get interactive input
from a user is frowned upon and not recommended.

My question is, am I really following a wrong approach here? Should I be doing it differently? How? I can't think of another solution on this specific problem.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interaction with the user while un/installing RPM is not a good practice. The philosophy behind it is that RPMs should able to be un/installed automatically, for example, when installed via YUM. If you must, you have several options:

Best: Create a script that get all information from the user, and write it to a file. In the RPM prerequisites, verify that the file exists.

Optional: Embed the RPM within a bash script that interacts with the user, extracts the RPM and run it. I believe Java RPM does it to let you accept the EULA.

Not a good idea: I have read somewhere that RPM reads from /dev/tty so you can try to add `exec 0</dev/tty` in the beginning of the %pre or %post